# How to automatically determine OS X boot partition based on day / time criteria?

Tags: macos

Imagine a single disk with two bootable partitions "Work" and "Play".

Is there a way to automatically boot from one or the other based on given criteria such as day or time?

For example (formatted as Swift):

```
   if (Day == Saturday || Day == Sunday) { 
       boot("Play")
   } else { 
       boot("Work")
   }
```

Side note, I realize this would need to be done prior to boot so bash would be more appropriate but swift is easier to read/write on the fly. :-)

Ideally the partition that is not booted would not be mounted either. Thus while "Work" is booted, "Play" is no where to be found and vice versa.

The underlying goal being to have the feeling of two completely separate machines without relying on an external boot drive. Similarly, two user accounts on one partition is not an option.

Comment: *"Hey, we've got an important emergency, can you check on your __work__ machine…?"* – Apart from this, you probably have to modify the firmware for this. Or perhaps a script on boot that checks the day and if it's the wrong partition for the day, modifies the boot config and reboots (rather clunky).

Comment: @deceze  So what your saying is, its not worth the effort, when compared to holding the option key on boot.  Kind of figured... but it never hurts to ask.